# How to get records missed after join on two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
TABLE AA

ID  NAME    EMAIL         TRAID STUSYID
-----------------------------------------
1   Ketan   ketan@test.com      1
2   Pankaj  pankaj@test.com PL1 5
3   Adil    adil@test.com   AS1 1
4   Lalit   lalit@test.com      7
5   Adil    adil@test.com   AS1 2
6   Adil    adil@test.com   AS1 3

TABLE AB

ID  NAME    EMAIL         TRAID STUSYID
-----------------------------------------
1   Pankaj  pankaj@test.com PL1 5
2   Lalit   lalit@test.com      7
3   Milind  milind@test.com     8
4   Akhi    akhi@test.com       8
5   Milind  milind@test.com     8
6   Pa      pankaj@test.com PL1 8
7   Adil1   adil@test.com   AS1 1
8   Adil2   adil@test.com   AS1 2
```

I want to get all detail from table a as below:

```
((select * from AA a JOIN AB b ON A.EMAIL = B.EMAIL AND A.TRAID IS NULL) 
union 
(select * from AA a JOIN AB b ON A.TRAID = B.TARID AND A.TRAID IS NOT NULL)
```

after getting above results i want to get all remaining results from table AB which are not availabe in above result set and i want to merge/union this entire result set (i want to fetch this entire result by exectuting one SQL statement.)

I am using oracle 11 g DB.

---

Edited to add results:

After suggestion from Richard, i have updated query as below:

```
select * from AA a FULL OUTER JOIN AB b 
ON (A.EMAIL = B.EMAIL AND A.STUSYID = B.STUDYID) 
OR (A.TRAID = B.TARID AND A.STUSYID = B.STUDYID)
```

And i am getting correct results as below:

```
    ID  NAME    EMAIL         TRAID STUSYID ID_1  NAME_1 EMAIL_1 TRAID_1 STUSYID_1
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 Ketan   ketan@test.com      1                   
2   Pankaj  pankaj@test.com PL1 5   1   Pankaj  pankaj@test.com PL1 5
3   Adil    adil@test.com   AS1 1   7   Adil1   adil@test.com   AS1 1
4   Lalit   lalit@test.com      7   2   Lalit   lalit@test.com      7
5   Adil    adil@test.com   AS1 2   8   Adil2   adil@test.com   AS1 2
6   Adil    adil@test.com   AS1 3                   
                                    3   Milind  milind@test.com     8
                                    4   Akhi    akhi@test.com       8
                                    5   Milind  milind@test.com     8
                                    6   Pa      pankaj@test.com PL1 8
```

This is what i want in result (All matching rows in two tables on the basis on either TARID or EMAIL(if TARID  is null)). 
But here i am getting very low performance of query if i do 'FULL OUTER JOIN'. Query cost is coming as 34000. Please suggest any way to get above results with good query performance.

**NOTE: Actual realtime query will have 7-8 other tables joins to get required data.**

Comment: Please edit your question and show the results that you are to get, using a table in the question.

Comment: And what's the wanted result?

Comment: You accepted the answer - and asked another question in the same. I suggest to ask a new question about the performance, if you cannot find a solution yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a *full outer join*:

```
select whatever
from A a
  full outer join B b 
    on (a.emailid = b.emailid)
      or (a.registrationid = b.registrationid)
```

which will return nulls where there is no matching row in A and also when there is no matching row in B.